# FME process first 100 features

Tags: fme-form

Is there a way in FME to process only, say, 100 records in a dataset? While developing a workspace I often have to iterate until I get it right. If the source dataset is large it's a waste of time to watch it process the whole thing just to do it again after tweaking a setting.

I'm thinking of something like using the counter transformer and a test, but that would still (partially) process all of the input data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your Navigator Window where your Reader is shown scroll down to Parameters your will find Features to Read.

Set Max Features to Read to 100.

[image]

Comment: Sweet! I generally ignore the Navigator window. I guess I'll have to dig into it a bit.